# Simple way to create a hierarchical tree of dynamic mbeans?

Tags: java, spring, scala, jmx, metrics

I want to expose dynamic hierarchical data in jmx
Is there a simple way to expose such dynamic mbeans?

I was looking at: [how to create dynamic mbeans](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2006/11/a_real_example.html)

but i don't like all this boilerplated code, I prefer not to invent the wheel, i'm using spring, is there a simple way to do this with spring? any other utility library which will ease the case?

Sample structure (**note account / features may come and go and thus jmx structure would be dynamically updated accordingly**)

```
accountA    
   --> FeatureA
       --> metric1: 1
       --> metric2: 5.5    
   --> FeatureB
       --> metric3: 1.1 
accountB 
. 
. 
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some starting points. GMBAL is used in GlassFish.

- [SimpleJMX](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/)
- [GMBAL](https://java.net/projects/gmbal/pages/Home)